# Need shortcut to New Document context submenu in Nautilus

Tags: nautilus, shortcut-keys

When the `nautilus` window has few files in "List view" (as opposed to "Grid view"), it is easy to click on an empty spot at the bottom of the list to get the context menu and find **New Folder** item and the **New Document** submenu.  However, when there are enough items in the folder to fill up the entire height of the window, it is not possible to get the same context menu.  One would have to switch to "Grid view" (<kbd>CRTL</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>) to find an empty spot and then do *right click* on an empty spot to get the proper context menu.

Of course, to get an empty folder one can always do <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>, regardless of the view, to get the new folder.  However, there is no such shortcut, that I know off, to get the **New Document** submenu.

Note that to quickly get to all the shortcuts in `nautilus` you can just do <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>.  You will see that on page 3 (Ubuntu 18.04) there is the "Editing" section with the shortcut for **New Folder** but none for **New Document**.

Anyone knows how one can create a shortcut directly to that submenu?

Comment: @pomsky thanks, retracted. Then I recommend to drop this degrading file-manager and replace it with full-featured one as Nemo, Thunar or Caja. I prefer Caja (it has *File->Create Document->Empty File*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>. This keystroke displays the context menu as if you right-clicked an empty space.

Alternatively, first make sure you don't have a file selected (if not, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to unselect it). Then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> to open the context menu (right-click menu). If your keyboard has a "[menu key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key)", you can use it instead of the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> combination.